# How to parse HTML with PHP?

Tags: php, html, regex, html-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

> **Suggestion for a reference question**. Stack Overflow has dozens of "How  to parse HTML" questions coming in every day. However, it is very difficult to close as a duplicate because most questions deal with the specific scenario presented by the asker. This question is an attempt to build a generic "reference question" that covers all aspects of the issue.
>
> This is an experiment. If such a reference question already exists, let me know and I'll happily remove this one.
>
> My ideal vision is that each of the three questions gets answered separately, and the best answers to each bubble up to the top.
>
> I will be awarding a **200 bounty** to the best answer in each of the three categories two weeks from now,  **pending [discussion of this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63762/do-reference-questions-make-sense) on Meta**.
>
> Each of these questions have already been answered brilliantly elsewhere, so copy+pasting your own answer to a different question is fine with me.

**How do I parse HTML with PHP?**

1. What libraries are there? Which ones use PHP's native DOM, which ones come with their own parsing engine? (Hint: SimpleHTMLDOM)

   1a. I need to find a specific element, but I find it hard to get used to the XPath syntax. Are there any DOM-based libraries that make parsing HTML easier? Please consider making generic real world examples.
2. Is there a PHP library that enables me to query the DOM using CSS[2/3] selectors, like jQuery does? (Hint: phpQuery) Please consider making generic real world examples.
3. Bonus question: Why shouldn't I use regular expressions? Please provide a very short answer in layman's terms.

Comment: @Pekka Yes, but that's just an excuse for those few people who actually *do* closevote to be as lazy as the ppl who asked the duplicate then. I understand why you feel like that. You know I closevote a lot. A reference question *would* make **my** life easier, but providing the answers here is not a good approach IMO. It's a CW. We don't get any reputation. Give people a chance to earn reputation for their answers. A link collection would be much better suited.