# Get full path to image from php

Tags: php

Hy!

I parse a website with simplehtml dom to get all links from the pictures.

The problem is that the link is like "/pics/bla.jpg".

I have the full path from the website like "http://xxx.xxx/blob/gulsch".

Now i want to get the full image link from the image (**link root + /pics/bla.jpg**) (no concat)
like: http://xxx.xxx/pics/bla.jpg

This should work for many websites

I tried it with explode()

```
$root = explode("/", $link);
echo $root[2];
```

I never get it working.

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Prepend a url to all links with no http or https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681049/php-prepend-a-url-to-all-links-with-no-http-or-https)

Comment: just wanted to know... why don't u wanna do concat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `parse_url`:

```
$r = parse_url($websiteUrl);
$imageUrl = $r["scheme"] . "://" . $r["host"] . "/" . $imageRelativeUrl;
```

The "root" of the website is simply `$r["host"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Given the parts of a URL, you can build a full URL with [`http_build_url`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php).