# Extracting HTML Data with Curl / PHP

Tags: php, string, wordpress, curl, cross-domain

I have the following code in PHP

```
$ch = curl_init("http://blog.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);      
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

I am trying to import the block of code in between `<div id="content">` and `</div>` I would like to know the best way of extracting this code.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650125/how-to-parse-html-with-php

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DOM would be the best way. Here's a detailed documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: This answer doesn't completely answer the question. Create a DOM using it doesn't show the DOM creation process.

Answer (score 1):

Using curl, the $output will be an String, so create a DOM using it:

`$html = str_get_html($content);`

Than, get the content:

`$content = $html->find('#content');`

Comment: thanks for your answer, but its not working in mine, when i try to pass string in str_get_html it will give me so many code