# Strip Tags short div

Tags: php, strip-tags

Hello
I have a lot of div tags, but I want to delete the div tag of characters in that little div tag.Number of string <10
ex

```
$txt=<<<HTML
 <div class="abc"> 123ab</div>
<div id="abc"> 123ab</div>

 <div class="abc"> 123abcdfdfsdfsdfdsfsdfsdfdsf</div>
HTML;
```

And return only dig(include long string)

```
$txt=<<<HTML
    <div class="abc"> 123abcdfdfsdfsdfdsfsdfsdfdsf</div>
HTML;
```

Comment: This calls for using a DOM parser. See e.g. this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650125/how-to-parse-html-with-php/3659729#3659729

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_replace('#<div(?:[^>]*)>.{0,10}</div>#u','',$txt)
```

not tested