# preg_replace throws seg fault

Tags: php, segmentation-fault, preg-replace

When I execute the following code; I get a seg fault every time!  Is this a known bug?  How can I make this code work?

```
<?php
$doc = file_get_contents("http://prairieprogressive.com/");
$replace = array(
    "/<script([\s\S])*?<\/ ?script>/",
    "/<style([\s\S])*?<\/ ?style>/",
    "/<!--([\s\S])*?-->/",
    "/\r\n/"
);
$doc = preg_replace($replace,"",$doc);
echo $doc;
?>
```

The error (obviously) looks like:

```
[root@localhost 2.0]# php test.php
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Have you ever thought of using a [proper HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650125/how-to-parse-html-with-php-closed)?

Comment: Just as a note I think you are missing the `>` after the script and style tags.

Comment: Show us the actual error. If you're getting a segfault it's likely an issue with your PHP installation. Or a bug. Either way, follow @Gumbo's advice and use an HTML parser.

Comment: @Gumbo This is part of the pre-processing to clean up typically troublesome tags before the page is parsed by DOMDocument

Comment: @Cfreak : I think it is a bug, I'm reproducing it on my laptop

Comment: @akellehe: It seems that doing this is more troublesome. :)

Comment: haha... troublesome indeed...  i seems the problem lies in the style regex: $doc = preg_replace("/<style([\s\S])*?<\/ ?style>/",'',$doc);
also throws the error by itself

Comment: Which version of PHP are you having this bug in? Because in 5.3.x its not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have unnecessary capture groups that strain PCRE's backtracking. Try this:

```
$replace = array(
    "/<script.*?><\/\s?script>/s",
    "/<style.*?><\/\s?style>/s",
    "/<!--.*?-->/s",
    "/\r\n/s"
);
```

Another thing, `\s` (whitespace) combined with `\S` (non-whitespace) matches anything. So just use the `.` pattern.

Answer (score 1):

OK! It seems like there is some issue with the () operators...

When I use

```
$doc = preg_replace("/<style([\s\S]*)<\/ ?style>/",'',$doc);
```

instead of

```
$doc = preg_replace("/<style([\s\S])*<\/ ?style>/",'',$doc);
```

it works!!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug.

As mentioned by you in the comment, it is the style regex that is causing this. As a workaround you can use the `s` modifier so that `.` matches even the newline:

```
$doc = preg_replace("/<style.*?<\/ ?style>/s",'',$doc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (added option u for unicode and changed ([\s\S])*? to .*? :

```
<?php
$doc = file_get_contents("http://prairieprogressive.com/");
$replace = array(
    "#<script.*?</ ?script>#u",
    '#<style.*?</ ?style>#u',
    "#<!--.*?-->#u",
    "#\r\n#u"
);
$doc = preg_replace($replace,"",$doc);
echo $doc;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of `[\s\S]`? It matches any whitespace character, and any non-whitespace character. If you replace it with `.*`, it works just fine.

EDIT: If you want to match new lines too, use the `s` modifier. In my opinion, it is easier to understand than a contradictory `[\s\S]`.

Comment: `.` by default does not match `\n` but `[\s\S]` does.

Comment: He can just use the `s` modifier then. Or even `[.\n]*`.

Comment: Yeah he can, but using `[\s\S]` is also valid.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `[\s\S]` instead of `(.|\n)` (but *not* `[.\n]`) or `.` with *s* modifier.