# PHP cURL to grab specific HTML

Tags: php, curl, html-parsing

I'm using this PHP:

```
<?php

$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.notrly.com/jackbauer/');
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

if (empty($buffer))
{
    print "Not today";
}
else
{
    print $buffer;
}
?>
```

There is a p tag with class "fact" in the source that i want to extract and display! How do i do it? Also is it against copyright if i use this to grab someone else HTML off of their site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use cURL, then download the page and use a DOM-parser like:

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Or you could just do something like this:

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$dom = file_get_html('http://www.notrly.com/jackbauer/');

foreach($dom->find("div.head div.fact p.fact") as $element)
    die($element->innertext);
```

Comment: excellent, once again, is that against some sort of copyright>

Comment: From what I can see, there is no copyright visible on the page. So I assume that it is publicly available.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `strpos` for looking in strings...

```
if (strpos($buffer, '<p class="fact">') !== FALSE) {
  print "Yay";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the HTML parsers mentioned in the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650125/how-to-parse-html-with-php).  As for copyright issues I think it would depend on many factors, including:

- What are you doing with the content
- How much of the content are you using
- What is the copyright on the site you
  are scraping

Comment: just displaying a quote on my website as a bit of fun. Not making any money from it or advertising etc

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, but if your just quoting a website its probably ok.  Bloggers do that all the time, often taking a paragraph or two from a website and then writing commentary.