# Regex to match 2 html tags in 1 HTML file

Tags: php, html, regex, html-parsing

I have a HTML file which contains the following:

```
<img src="MATCH1" bla="blabla">
<something:else bla="blabla" bla="bla"><something:else2 something="something">
<something image="MATCH2" bla="abc">
```

Now I need a regex to match both MATCH1 and MATCH2

Also the HTML contains multiple parts like this, so it can be in the HTML 1, 2, 3 of x times..

When I say:

```
<img\s*src="(.*?)".*?<something\s*image="(.*?)"
```

It doesn't match it. What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Needs `/ims`, but you should also split it up into two regexps.

Comment: Regex leads to the dark side, young padawan.

Comment: -1 because **nobody** needs regex to parse html; plus the question has been asked million thousands times and the answer has always been, **nobody** needs regex to parse html. Also your answer to NAVEED was rude, and implied he didn't know what he was talking about, which is not true.

Answer (score 10):

[Regex does not always provide perfect result while parsing HTML.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#2146912)

I think you should do it using [HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

**For Example:**

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/');

// OR Create a DOM object from a HTML file
$html = file_get_html('test.htm');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

There are filters to get tags with specific attributes:

> **[attribute]** Matches elements that have
>   the specified attribute.
>
> **[attribute=value]** Matches elements
>   that have the specified attribute with
>   a certain value.
>
> **[attribute!=value]** Matches elements
>   that don't have the specified
>   attribute with a certain value.
>
> **[attribute^=value]** Matches elements
>   that have the specified attribute and
>   it starts with a certain value.
>
> **[attribute$=value]** Matches elements
>   that have the specified attribute and
>   it ends with a certain value.
>
> **[attribute*=value]** Matches elements
>   that have the specified attribute and
>   it contains a certain value.

[More Options](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

There are also some other Parsing Tools to parse HTML as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662).

Comment: Well I need to use regex. I've done it before but I can't remember what I did so I know it's possible...

Comment: @CyberK: I have also done it using regex before and I spent lot of time finding out specific regex patterns for different HTML codes. And the result was not always perfect. Finally I realized to use a HTML Parser. Anyway it is also a solution. May be you will get a good regex.

Comment: This is definitely the easiest way. I used to parse html with regex too, but the headaches it brings are NEVER worth it! Heed the advice and use a proper html parser

Comment: @mario: I did not know the history behind this. Anyway I replaced this with your provided link.

Comment: Thank you. (And anyway the link isn't forbidden yet. Just redundant if you have a better answer.)

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, I'll better elaborate before more anti-regex memers come around. In your case it is actually applicable to use regular expressions. However I'd like to point out, that you should carefully evaluate on [the pros and cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650125/how-to-parse-html-with-php/3650431#3650431).

It's mostly simpler to use phpQuery or QueryPath for such tasks:

```
qp($html)->find("img")->attr("src");
```

But a regex is possible too, if you don't overlook the gritty details:

```
preg_match('#<img[^>]+src="([^">]*)".+?<something\s[^>]*image="([^">]*)"#ims', $html, $m);
```

If extraction depends on the presence of both tags, then it might be a better option here.