# How To Use Different Regex Patterns In Preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Please I have this line;

```
preg_match_all('/((\w+)?)/'
```

But I want to also match this pattern in the same preg_match_all

```
\S+[\.]?\s?\S*
```

How can I go about it in PHP

Comment: What's wrong with [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)? BTW, `[\.]?` is `\.?` and your first regex can be changed to `/\w*/`.

Comment: Possible duplication? [Find multiple patterns with a single preg_match_all in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536014/find-multiple-patterns-with-a-single-preg-match-all-in-php)

Comment: Could you tell us _what_ are you trying to match (not _how_)?

Answer (score 4):

- Your patterns probably don't work all that well (they look cobbled together)
- That being said, the way to say `OR` in regex is the alternation operator `|`
- Therefore you could join them with `$regex = "~\S+[\.]?\s?\S*|((\w+)?)~";`

**... but in my view this pattern needs a beauty job. :)**

1. `\S+[\.]?\s?\S*` can be tidied up as `\S+\.?\s?\S*`, but the `\S+` will eat up the `\.` so you probably need a lazy quantifier: `\S+?\.?\s?\S*`... But this is just some solid chars + an optional dot + one optional space + optional solid chars... So the period in the middle can go, as `\S` already specified it. We end up with `\S+\s?\S*`
2. `((\w+)?)` is just `\w*`, unless you need a capture group.
3. But `\S+\s?\S*` is able to match everything `\w*` matches, except for the empty string, so you can reduce this to `\S+\s?\S*`

**Finally**

Therefore, you would end up with something like:

```
$regex = "~\S+\s?\S*~";
$count = preg_match_all($regex,$string,$matches);
```

If you do want this to also be able to match the empty string, as `((\w+)?)` did, then make the whole thing optional:

```
$regex = "~(?:\S+\s?\S*)?~";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just combine the regexes like below using an logical OR(`|`) operator,

```
$regex = "~/(?:((\w+)?)|\S+[\.]?\s?\S*)/~"
```

`(?:)` represents a non-capturing group.

It would print the strings which are matched by first or second regex.