# Check if div ID exists (PHP)

Tags: php, element

Is it possible to check if an element exists with PHP?

I'm aware of the javascript method already but I just want to avoid it if possible.

Comment: What are your reasons for doing it server side?

Comment: A what element? An HTML element in an HTML document?

Comment: Yes for example `<div id="test"></div>` if that doesn't exist `echo 'Test doesn't exist'`

Comment: @Daryl where is the HTML document located? Are you loading it into PHP?

Comment: you want to check out HTML parsers like the ones discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650125/how-to-parse-html-with-php  In any event, it's generally best to avoid regexes for HTML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662)

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko Well I'm trying to make this website as friendly as possible, meaning if some moron has JS switched off I don't want things to break too much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have the HTML server side in a string, you can use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```
<?php
$html = '<html><body><div id="first"></div><div id="second"></div></body></html>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$element = $dom->getElementById('second');
// this will be null if it isn't found
var_dump($element);
```

Comment: *DOMDocument* objects have a [`getElementById` method](http://php.net/domdocument.getelementbyid).

Comment: how does he uses this on the clientside? -> he will have to use ajax!

Comment: Haha, cheers Gumbo, completely forgot about that. I've been doing too much screen scraping lately. Will update.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, because PHP is serverside only.

But if you really wish to do so, you may send the whole code of your page to a php script on your server using an ajax request, parse it there to find out if a div with a specified ID exists (see Shabbyrobes post; sure this would be very ineffective and is not recommended when you can easily check it with javascript...) and return the result in your ajax response.

Answer (score -1):

No. PHP can only serve content, it has no control or view of the DOM except what you ask it to create.

Comment: Yes php serves multiple classes to control a DOM. For instance lets say the DomDocument class. Not really perfect if it comes to html that is not good formatted but its there.