# How to loop through posts content and show only a specifc id or class

Tags: php, wordpress

I know that I can do this via CSS or javaScript but I wonder if Wordpress has a native way of doing this.

I have this code:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 

                        <?php the_content(); ?>
```

But let's say, I just want to show a specific id or class contained in all those posts. Ex: `#heading` or `.heading`

How can I do that?

Comment: with ID you mean a specific field from the post object?
btw.. the above code is not an html element (its a php code block) ;-)

Comment: Sorry, it is is 'within' an html element:) Yes, I have posts that contain a specific html id. The big picture is: in one element of the page I want to show all the posts and content, while in another html element of the page I want to show only a particular html id included in all those posts.But for this last case I couldn't find any answer on google. Of course, I can use css display: none but all the content of the posts has to be loaded and I wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: If I understood you correctly you want to show content(particular html id) from the posts in a different element. You still need to loop through every post. 

if the particular html id you looking for is inside the_content() there is as far as I know no way to get only that portion. if it's a custom field you still need to loop through the posts but instead of the_content() you just grab the appropriate field.

Comment: Thank you very much! I needed to have a confirmation that is not possible without looping through all content or that wordpress doesn't have a way of exclude content while looping it. So, in this particular case I will use CSS and display none all the content apart from that html id. If you answer I will accept it.

Comment: Is it what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594609/check-if-div-id-exists-php ?

Comment: It is kind of and it helped it. Thank you:) Through the other comments I understood Wordpress has no way of excluding/selecting content whithin the posts while looping it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get only the post containing id="heading" with PHP:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 

$post_content = get_the_content();
$find_this = 'id="heading"';
$find_this_single_quote = "id='heading'";

if (strpos($post_content, $find_this) !== false || strpos($post_content, $find_this_single_quote ) !== false) {
    the_content();
}
```

Then, filter the result with jQuery to get only the contents of #heading:

```
var content = $('#heading').html();

if (content != '') {
        $('#real-content').html(content);
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hyxhn7mg/1/

Comment: Thank you:) I am going to try it:)

Comment: I don't think you'll get anything from this since it's searching through HTML and in HTML you won't find #heading, you will find id="heading" try changing the string for $find_this to 'id="heading"';

Comment: Umm, [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) does not return `TRUE`.  It returns an *integer*, or else `FALSE`.  So, what you mean to write is `if ( $pos !== FALSE ) {`....

Comment: @viery365 did it work? mind to upvote and accept answer?

Comment: @LucasB Sorry, yesterday I didn't have time afterwards, I am going to try this morning:)

Comment: @LucasB So, I tested it out, and what this does (and I can call it a learning for me) is something like: show the content of a post if the post has "id="heading"" written on it. This is great, and can be useful for the future of my code. But what I really wanted seems kind of impossible in the server side with wordpress. It would be something like. If the post contains "id="heading"" show only the content inside of that id. so if that id contained `<p>Hello</p>` the result of the loop would only show `<p>Hello</p>`. But thank you very much for your time and consideration.

Comment: @viery365 Perhaps you could print the content to a hidden div, then run a jQuery like this: https://jsfiddle.net/hyxhn7mg/1/

Comment: @LucasB Thank you very much! I did something similar using only display: none, but your solution is even better because the loop only runs once and that was what I wanted. It was more of a performance wise question. If you answer with your last comment and add that via wordpress itself is not possible, I will accept it:) Thank you again

Comment: @viery365 Updated the answer