# php html parsing using DOMXPath

Tags: php, html, parsing

I have html like this:

> ```
> <span><b>Company: </b>
>     Nirmal Datacomm Pvt Ltd<br>
>   <b>location: </b>
>         Mumbai<br>
>   <b>Ref: </b> 
>      8560918<br> </span>
> ```

I want to extract the bold text and the text immediately following it into an array like the following:

```
array('company'=>'Nirmal DataComm Pvt Ltd','location'=>'Mumbai','ref'=>'8560918')
```

I am new to PHP. By going through related questions, I learnt that it can be done using DOMXPath (if i'm not wrong). I read several other examples about using DOMXPath but could not get any clue for query.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks and Regards

Chandra

Answer (score 0):

Please check [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650125/how-to-parse-html-with-php) wonderful stackoverflow page. I think it will help you to solve your problem. Basically, [querypath](http://querypath.org/) and [phpquery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) this 2 tool can help you. For more reference check that article please.

Comment: I m sorry. That was not my requirement! I need to store the HTML content into an array.

Comment: I'm soory,too. I think regular expression can solve your problem also. For example if you use preg_match_all("/<b>(.*)<\/b>/U", $str, $bold); here $str is your string(Your HTML input) and $bold will be an array which contain all the <b>....</b>. Similarly other pattern can be easily build. For more information please check the php manual.