# use preg match and replace to replace li tags within ol tags

Tags: php, tags, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-replace-callback

Here is what i got:

```
<ol>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ol>

<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>


if (preg_match("/<ol>.*(<li(|\s*\/)>).*<\/ol>/Ums", $text->Bodytext)) {
$cleanlist = preg_replace("/(<li(|\s*\/)>)/", "<li><tag>", $text->Bodytext);
```

This php code works well if the page only contains ol tags, but if it contains both ul and ol tags for some reason it changes li tags inside ul tags too and I only want it to replace it within ol tags. What could be the problem and how can i fix it?

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your regex is likely the greedyness. You should append a question mark to `.*?` so it matches less padding.

It would however be more reliable it you didn't try to accomplish it with a single regex. That's always a bit more involving then going the simple route:

```
$html = preg_replace_callback('#<ol>(.*?)</ol>#Us', "change_li", $html);
function change_li($m) {
    return preg_replace('#<li>#', '<li><tag>', $m[0]);
}
```

Now before the meme posters come around, using regular expressions is not the most reliable approach. It's workable in your case unless you have wacky HTML. An alternative would be to use [phpQuery or QueryPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650125/how-to-parse-html-with-php) however, where matching is as simple as `qp($html)->find("ol")->find("li")`. Though the actual replacing would be more involving with that approach.

Comment: Ok, after trying to get this code to work on the site i am getting some errors. i replaced $html with $text->Bodytext since that is what i need in the site and got this error "Warning:  preg_replace_callback() [function.preg-replace-callback]: Requires argument 2, 'change_li', to be a valid callback"

Comment: @user585303: Well it needs to be a function. If you added it as method, then the callback must be `array($this,"change_li")` or whatever.

Comment: Another interesting story, here is the case <ol><ol>
<li>abc</li></ol>
<ul>
<li>ghi</li>
<li>jkl</li>
</ul>
<li>def</li>

</ol> when i have ol within the ol it stops working or also its stops converting the other li s within the first ol tag, any suggestions?

Comment: @user585303: Well that's over your head to accomplish with regular expressions. Use the recommended phpQuery then.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 5.3 this task could be done as follows:

```
        $input = <<<END
<ol>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ol>

<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
END;



        $result = preg_replace_callback(
                "/(<ol>.*<\/ol>)/Ums",
                function ($ol) {
                    return preg_replace("/(<li(|\s*\/)>)/", "<li><tag>", $ol[1]);                    
                },
                $input
        );

        var_dump($result);
```

The output would be:

```
        string '<ol>
<li><tag></li>
<li><tag></li>
</ol>

<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>' (length=72)
```