# php explode select multi choose

Tags: php, explode

I want divide these html as serval several part. One `<h2>` or `<h3>` with some `<p>` and `<span>` as one part. I tried `explode` `array('<h2>','<h3>')`, but it caused `Warning`. the `explode` not support multi choose.

So how to do it perfectly? Thanks.

```
$text=<<<EOT
<h2>title1</h2>
<p>something</p>
<span>something</span>
<h3>title2</h3>
<p>something</p>
<p>something</p>
<p>something</p>
<h2>title3</h2>
<span>something</span>
<h2>title4</h2>
<span>something</span>
<p>something</p>
<p>something</p>
EOT;

foreach ($text as $result) { 
    $arr = explode(array('<h2>','<h3>'),$result);
    reset($arr); 
    foreach($arr as $line){
        echo $line.'<hr />';
    } 
}
```

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 23;`

My expected output is:

```
<h2>title1</h2>
<p>something</p>
<span>something</span>
___________________________
<h3>title2</h3>
<p>something</p>
<p>something</p>
<p>something</p>
___________________________
<h2>title3</h2>
<span>something</span>
___________________________
<h2>title4</h2>
<span>something</span>
<p>something</p>
<p>something</p>
___________________________
```

Comment: `reset($arr); ` is not necessary; `foreach` works on a copy of the array. Besides that, string functions and regexes are both no proper way to deal with HTML.

Comment: The warning is addressed to the `foreach`, not the `explode`. You are trying to loop a `string` ($text) instead of an `array`.

Comment: @cj333 Can you post your expected output?

Comment: @Jürgen Thelen: Post this comment as an answer.

Comment: @Brendan Bullen, add my `expected output`.

Comment: @M42: done, but too late (was busy) ^^

Comment: You need a proper HTML browser to do this. See [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/3577662#3577662)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`preg_split()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to `explode` at different things. You can use RegEx here:

```
$text = <<<EOT
<h2>title1</h2>
<p>something</p>
...
EOT;

$arr = preg_split("#(?=<h[23]>)#", $text);

if(isset($arr[0]) && trim($arr[0])=='') array_shift($arr); // remove first block if empty

foreach($arr as $block){
    echo $block."<hr />\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a parser for this kind of tasks. I use Zend Framework which has a [parser component](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.query.htmlhttp://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.query.html). Otherwise you can use plain [PHP DOMElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php). Then you can query your dom with xpath or css selectors. Example:

```
<?php

$text=<<<EOT
<h2>title1</h2>
<p>something</p>
<span>something</span>
<h3>title2</h3>
<p>something</p>
<p>something</p>
<p>something</p>
<h2>title3</h2>
<span>something</span>
<h2>title4</h2>
<span>something</span>
<p>something</p>
<p>something</p>
EOT;


require_once 'Zend/Dom/Query.php';

$dom = new Zend_Dom_Query($text);
$results = $dom->query('h2');

foreach ($results as $domEl) {
    var_dump($domEl->nodeValue);
}
// outputs:
// string(6) "title1"
// string(6) "title3"
// string(6) "title4"
```

**Edit**: Given your expected output, my example doesn't fit exactly your needs, but you still need a parser to do that kind of HTML manipulation, because the parser splits the HTML in elements and you can manipulate them as tokens, not as text.

Comment: You can get different elements using different queries on the same dom object or if you know xpath you can build complex queries, which retrieves all your needed elements. If you never heard of xpath go with separate queries because xpath is powerful but harder to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first, the warning is addressed to the [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), not the `explode`. You are trying to loop a `string` (`$text` in this case) instead of an `array`.

Second, even if `$text` would be of type array and `$result` would be of type string, you are trying to use an `array` as delimiter in the [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) call, but that function wants the 1st parameter to be of type `string`.

I'd recommend to have a look at [How to parse HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3650125/693207) or to [search SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20parse%20html) for this terms, to find many many posts dealing with how to parse HTML with PHP.