# XML mapping to Database

Tags: php, xml

I don't know if anyone can help me with this. But can anyone tell me how can I map an XML script into mysql database? Lets say the web service provider has a XML script that returns the hotel classifications. Instead of running this script everytime I run a search query, I want it to save into the database and use the database table instead of the XML script.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: XML code... I don't know if you understand what I'm saying

Comment: What is XML code? Do you just mean an XML document? I've never heard of an XML script or XML code.

Comment: ok lets say XML document

Comment: Good luck, but remember, just because you're using PHP doesn't mean that everything is a script.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't work with XML from a webservice directly. Use a proxy class which automatically serialize and desearialize the XML for you into a "Hotel" object.

Comment: Well can you tell me this in a simpler way?
I'm still a noob in using XML.
I'm using PHP by the way

Comment: Not too familiar with PHP, but you can start looking at this: http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Serializer

Answer (score 0):

Put your XMl into a `SimpleXMLElement` object.  You can find an example of how to do that via my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241461/how-to-read-xml-file-and-fetch-values-from-it-to-display-in-php-coded-html-page/7243953#7243953).