# Get image url from RSS feed description using PHP

Tags: php, function

I want to get the url of an image (where it's stored) from the description of a RSS feed, so then I can put that url inside a variable.

I know that for getting the link of the RSS feed post I have to use `$feed->channel->item->link;` where `$feed` is `$feed=simplexml_load_file("link_of_the_feed";`.

But what if I have get the image url of the post, do I have to use something like `$feed->channel->item->image;`?

I really don't know, maybe a RSS parser like MagPie RSS which I tried without results?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the `image` node is at the top level of the `item` node, then yes.  If it's deeper than the `item` node, you'll have to traverse it accordingly.  It would be helpful if you posted your XML.

**EDIT**: you can also check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241461/how-to-read-xml-file-and-fetch-values-from-it-to-display-in-php-coded-html-page/7243953#7243953) on how to parse through an XML file with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track! But it all depends on the format that the RSS Feed is set up in.

The `item` node actually contains a whole bunch of different fields, of which `link` is only one. Take a look [here](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html#hrelementsOfLtitemgt) for information on the other fields that the `item` node contains.

Now, if the RSS feed points directly to the image file, then you can just use `item->link`. More likely, however, the link points to a blog post or something that has the image embedded in it. In this case, you can undertake some processing on `$feed->channel->item->description` to find what you need. The `description` node contains an escaped HTML summary of the post, and then from there, you can just use a [regular expression](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) to find the source of the image. Also remember: before you start using the regular expressions, you might need to decode the `description` using `htmlspecialchars_decode()` before you start processing it with the regular expressions - in my own experience, descriptions often come formatted with special characters escaped.

I know that's a lot of information, but once you get started it's really not as hard as it sounds. Good luck!

Comment: So I must break into pieces the description and find with regular expressions only the part where <img> appears, right?

Comment: Yep, spot on :) and then from there, you're looking for the `src` attribute of the image.