# Need help with preg_replace of links with images (php)

Tags: php, regex, dom, find, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650125/how-to-parse-html-with-php)
>   [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/regular-expression-for-grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element/3820783#3820783)

I have some random text with images in a href tag like this:

```
<a title="Some title" rel="lightbox" href="http://www.test.com/DSCF0733.jpg"><img class="alignleft size-thumbnail wp-image-504" title="some title" src="http://www.test.com/Dhghjkhjl33-150x150.jpg" alt="description" width="145" height="145" /></a>
```

I want to find them all and put to an array. Text can contain other links, but we need only with rel lightbox.
Please, help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the built in [DOMDocument()](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), simple yet effective & safer then regex...

```
<?php 
$site=file_get_contents('http://example.com');

$xml = new DOMDocument();
@$xml->loadHTML($site);


foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('a') as $links) {
    //Check for lightbox within the link
    if($links->getAttribute('rel')=='lightbox'){ 
        //Assign
        $imgLinks[]=$links->getAttribute('href');
    }
}

print_r($imgLinks);
?>
```

Comment: I think the OP want to find all `src` attributes of `img` tags that are inside `a` tags that have `rel="lightbox"`. You're (trying) to find all `href` values of `a` tags that have `rel="lightbox"`.

Comment: Also note that you spelled `'herf'` instead of `'href'`.

Comment: lol whoops on the typo ;s the op specifically said `href tag` and then `find them all and put to an array` thanks tho

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity use [phpQuery or QueryPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650125/how-to-parse-html-with-php):

```
include "qp.phar";
foreach (htmlqp($html)->find("a[rel=lightbox]") as $a) {
    $links[] = $a->attr("href");
}
```

But you can also modify the contained text or other attributes. (The preg_*replace* part of your question might need elaboration.)