# regex to find a specific tag by content

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've 2 (or more) `script` tag in my html page, and i want to remove (replace with `' '`)  them, *which one has `myfunc` in its content* (only `script` tags).
an example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunc(){
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Hello World!");
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(myfunc());
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

I'm looking for a RegEx to do that, for php `preg_replace`.

Thank you, very much.

Comment: Where are you getting the HTML from? If the PHP script is the one outputting it then why don't you just not output the `<script>` tag in question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650125/how-to-parse-html-with-php)

Comment: @Tarek: it's a part of my html page, I import the page's code into my php program, change and replace that, and save it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<script type=\"text\/javascript\">(.*myfunc\(\).*?)<\/script>`

replace it with

`\1`