# How to get current URL and change parameter PHP

Tags: php, url, request-uri

I have a URL like this:

```
muliba/?i=page.alama&pro=as
```

And I created a link like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]."&pro=as";?>">AS</a>
<a href="<?php echo http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]."&pro=en";?>">EN</a>
```

If I open the link, the parameter is added next to already defined one like so:

```
muliba/?i=page.alama&pro=as&pro=en
```

How can I get result like this?

```
muliba/?i=page.alama&pro=as
muliba/?i=page.alama&pro=en
```

Thanks

Comment: I wrote something a few years ago that might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356555 It will replace parts of the query string like what you need eg `merge_querystring($url,'?pro=as')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [better way to replace query string value in a given url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356555/better-way-to-replace-query-string-value-in-a-given-url)

Comment: Im sorry, I still don't understand.. please help me for that case.. cause my link is different..

Comment: Well what happens when you try `merge_querystring( 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?pro=as' )` ? It's the exact same use case as the thread I've linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`Scuzzy`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61795/scuzzy) answer  and [`jlcolon13`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3251470/jlcolon13) Modifications on [`Scuzzy`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61795/scuzzy) answer in this [`Question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356555) I merge both answers to make it simpler for you. Just Copy code below and paste it into your file!.

```
function merge_querystring($url = null,$query = null,$recursive = false){
  // $url = 'https://www.google.com?q=apple&type=keyword';
  // $query = '?q=banana';
  // if there's a URL missing or no query string, return
  if($url == null)
    return false;
  if($query == null)
    return $url;
  // split the url into it's components
  $url_components = parse_url($url);
  // if we have the query string but no query on the original url
  // just return the URL + query string
  if(empty($url_components['query']))
    return $url.'?'.ltrim($query,'?');
  // turn the url's query string into an array
  parse_str($url_components['query'],$original_query_string);
  // turn the query string into an array
  parse_str(parse_url($query,PHP_URL_QUERY),$merged_query_string);
  // merge the query string
  if ($recursive == true) {
    $merged_result = array_filter(array_merge_recursive($original_query_string, $merged_query_string));
} else {
    $merged_result = array_filter(array_merge($original_query_string, $merged_query_string));
}

// Find the original query string in the URL and replace it with the new one
$new_url = str_replace($url_components['query'], http_build_query($merged_result), $url);

// If the last query string removed then remove ? from url 
if(substr($new_url, -1) == '?') {
   return rtrim($new_url,'?');
}
return $new_url;
}
```

Usage

```
<a href="<?=merge_querystring($url,'?pro=en');?>">EN</a>
<a href="<?=merge_querystring($url,'?pro=as');?>">AS</a>
```

**Special thanks to** [`Scuzzy`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61795/scuzzy) & [`jlcolon13`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3251470/jlcolon13)

Comment: Thanks for all, I've tried this code,  $url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 $dis_url=trim(strtok($url, '&')); and it works.