# Detecting </span> in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a script that checks the source of another page, I'm having my code search for

```
 <span class="item-header">
```

in the source. When it finds it, I wan't to print everything that is in the span, but I am not sure how I would do that in PHP? How do I check when to stop printing everything after the span until it finds `</span>` Here is my code:

```
 if (stristr($source, '<span class="item-header">')){
   // What to do here?
 }
```

Any Ideas? :)

Comment: profit! http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: This is what you needed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650125/how-to-parse-html-with-php

Comment: Please use search... so many answers can be found

Comment: why is this question voted down? I see good question in it. Granted, this is repeated question. But how the hell newcomers know this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regex, but people will caution against parsing HTML with regex. I would recommend using DOMDocument to parse the HTML and DOMXPath to query the document tree. Try this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($page);
$dom_xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$entries = $dom_xpath->evaluate("//span[@class='item-header']");
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    print $entry->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you - but when I tested this, nothing printed. I set $page to the URL of the page.

Comment: Nevermind, I set $page as the source and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex: if you find this question is match to your problem, mark it as accepted: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 1):

You would likely be better off using [an actual parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead of regex-based searches. That way you could grab the node for the span and get the text value.