# screen scraping with curl

Tags: php, curl, screen-scraping

so far my cURL code i have written displays the page that I would like after it automatically logs me into a website, however i am stuck on the issue of screen scraping. I would like to now sort through some more information from this data. here is what i want to sort out of the page:

```
<div class="quantity">
    Avail. Quantity:<span>75</span>
</div>
```

I specifically would like to grab the number inside the `<span>` which in this case would be `75`. how could i do this with curl?

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to read a web page and want to extract data from it?

Comment: yes. i used curl because i had to log into the web page to view it, and now i would like to extract data from the page that i've logged into

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument) or one of the simpler library frontends like [`phpQuery`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650125/how-to-parse-html-with-php) or [`QueryPath`](http://querypath.org/). Then it's as easy as using a CSS selector:

```
print htmlqp($url)->find(".quantity span")->text();
```

(Note that page retrieval is already built-in here, but you could also just pass your `$html` variable.)

Comment: i installed it but im getting an error saying: Fatal error: Call to undefined function text() in /home/frostyc/public_html/crawl.php on line 73

Comment: Ah, evil syntax typo. It was missing a `->` (so tried to call a global function instead).