# Ignore class attribute when extracting content from HTML body tag with a regex

Tags: php, regex, class, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)
>   [How to parse HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650125/how-to-parse-html-with-php)

I am trying to get what's inside a body tag using regex, but it doesn't work in some cases.

For example if a web page has:

```
<body>text</body>
```

it will work, but it won't work if the body tag has a class or something defined, like

```
<body class="something">text</body>
```

I need the regex to work on both cases.

Comment: `Change [ with < and ] with >.` Done.

Comment: What regular expression are you currently using?

Comment: [`xpath_match_all('//body', $html);`](https://gist.github.com/1358174)

Comment: Isn't body tag optional?

Comment: -1 This is a **Bad Idea™**

Why?
See 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2):

Use `[^>]*>` after 'body' word:

```
<body[^>]*>.*</body>
```

Comment: You forgot the \ sign before /. `<body[^>]*>.*<\/body>`. Thank you.

Comment: @Zeus: if this answered your question, please mark it as so (this helps to keep the site "clean").