# How to replace all html tags in a php string using RegEx

Tags: php, regex

How to replace all html tags in a php string using RegEx

Tried as follows but fails,

```
$r = "<h1>Hai</h1><br/><p>Hello world</p>";


$result = preg_replace('<(.*)>', '', $r);



echo $result ;
```

Expected Result:

`Hai Hello world` as just in string format

Comment: Do you need to use regular expressions? There is strip-tags function in PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: @MateuszMrozewski Post it as an answer.

Comment: [Must read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650125/how-to-parse-html-with-php)

Answer (score 2):

place a question mark after `.*`

```
$r = "<h1>Hai</h1><br/><p>Hello world</p>";
$result = preg_replace('<(.*?)>', '', $r);
echo $result ;
```

`.*` is a greedy regex and will match all until the **last** `>` character. `.*?` is lazy and will match until the **first** `>` character.

Answer (score 2):

How about strip_tags usage instead of regex ?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: with strip_tags, the output will be "HaiHello world"

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is failing because the `*` is a greedy operator - it consumes all characters including the `>` character. Try the following:

```
$result = preg_replace('<(.*?)>', '', $r);
```

However, as @MateuszMrozewski points out, using the strip tags functions would probably be best way to solve this problem.