# Alternative to regexes for parsing html tags - How do you do it in pure code?

Tags: php, regex

Recently read this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) ...first answer is nutz.  Basically it is theoretically impossible for large models because of Chomsky Grammars Types.

What it the alternative? I don't want to use a library object like DOMDocument, I want to understand what is the correct way to do this with pure code?

Comment: What is the difference between *pure code*, and a library (which is written as pure code)?

Comment: What's the difference between writing the regex which my guess will work 99.9% of the time and using DOMDocument()?

Comment: If you discovered that page, why not read past the joke answers? (Hint: the uninformed confuse parsing and extracting). And why in the world was [more accurate coverage of the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650125/how-to-parse-html-with-php) that hard to find? This comes up five times per week!

Comment: Why can't a Chomsky Grammar Type 2 by analyzed by a Chomsky Grammar Type 3?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la

Comment: Those answers are highly theoretical examples for people trying to model entire web pages...for a simple tag grab...I don't think it will be problem...that can not be solved with a regex.  Thanks for the little blue links.

Comment: But with in those libraries which I don't have time to read..they are extracting the html tags with 0 or 0+ regexes.  I would have to guess they are using basic string type functions with logic, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) (though I'd urge you to look into it again, it's not that bad - especially combined with [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)), you can also use [PHPQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) or [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).