# Regex for script tag in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am using a regex to grab content of all script tag of an html page.
the regex and code I use is like:

```
$content = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create(
                    array("http" => array("user_agent" => "any"))
            ));

$pattern = "/<script[^>]*?>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $inside_script_array);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($inside_script_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

when I take 1.>

```
$url = 'http://www.bestylish.com/' ;
```

it returns me all the script tag . but when I take 2.>

```
$url = 'http://www.bestylish.com/sale' ;
```

it doesn't reply me many tags which are same and present in above url 1. What should be the reason ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650125/how-to-parse-html-with-php)

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that regular expressions are not a good tool to manipulate HTML. If you still have the option to switch to a DOM parser, fetching `<script>` tags can be as simple as:

```
$domd = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$domd->loadHTML(file_get_contents('http://www.google.com'));
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

$items = $domd->getElementsByTagName('script');
$data = array();

foreach($items as $item) {
  $data[] = array(
    'src' => $item->getAttribute('src'),
    'outerHTML' => $domd->saveHTML($item),
    'innerHTML' => $domd->saveHTML($item->firstChild),
  );
}

print_r($data);
```