# How can I parse this PARTICULAR HTML table into a php array?

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom, domparser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)
>   [How to parse HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650125/how-to-parse-html-with-php)

http://www.nfl.com/widget/gc/2011/tabs/cat-post-boxscore?gameId=2012093000

I am looking to scrape the data from pages like the link above (that is, game level NFL data).

NFL.com has a handy JSON API that makes a lot of this data accessible. That is, for games 2010 and later.  For earlier games, I am going to have to parse the HTML of pages similar to the one above.

I've bene using Simple HTML Dom, but am running into trouble collecting all of the data (because it is of variable length) in the tr class='tbdy1' tags.

Comment: Actually I meant to link to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php

Comment: can we unclose this question? i meed help on this particular html scrape

Comment: The current question doesn't contain a specific question and the linked questions are an answer to the current question. Feel free to change the question if you think you can make it specific and not duplicate. If you have done so just let me know and I'll have a look.