# Pregmatch all hrefs from a

Tags: php, html, css, preg-match

I've been trying to `pregmatch` `hrefs` from a site but I'm running into some problems.
I want to get all `hrefs` from the page that look like this:

```
<a class="truncate openwindow" target="_blank" href="/50440225" title="Blah">
```

There are at least 20 other hrefs like this but with different 8-digit numbers for the specific business site. Pre-match gives me an only empty array.
Thanks

Comment: dont use regex use a dom parser.

Comment: This has to be a dupe... Also, maybe show what you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650125/how-to-parse-html-with-php